# Require Secure Connections (HTTPS) field in production environment

Tags: sandbox, production

I have a force.com site. Currently it has http, I would like to change it to https in production environment. I wanted to changed it to https by checking the checkbox Require Secure Connections(HTTPS) in production , but it is not present there. However, I have this checkbox in sandbox environment. Can you please tell me why this checkbox is not present in production environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your sandbox must be on Winter 15 release. That is a new feature that is available in the next release. It will be available in production in October. Here's the release schedule: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/